# Plotting points on Canvas using an Array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

So my teacher wanted us to create a canvas. He gave us some really confusing instructions that I cannot make sense of.

> Using a path, plot the points from the array and display them as a
>   line graph. Adjust the x coordinate for each member of the array and
>   adjust the y coordinate to show the value of each member.Remember, the
>   y coordinate in the canvas puts 0 at the top of the screen so you will
>   need to subtract each array value from the graph height + border since
>   most line graphs show data that is relative to the bottom of the graph
>   rather than the top. The x coordinate should be adjusted by the unit
>   spacing for each array value. I would strongly recommend using a for
>   loop.

I would really like an explanation on what this means and how to do it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag
     </canvas>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Java Script :

```
graph();

function graph() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var theContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var sales = [52, 48, 74, 31, 47, 25, 67, 78, 45, 15, 85];
  var width = 300;
  var height = 100; 
  var uSpacing = 10;
  var border = 20;
  var scalar = 100;

  theContext.strokeRect(border, border, width, height)
  theContext.beginPath();
  theContext.moveTo(100,100);
  theContext.lineTo(52,48);
  theContext.stroke();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```js
graph();

function graph() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var theContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var sales = [52, 48, 74, 31, 47, 25, 67, 78, 45, 15, 85];
  var width = 300;
  var height = 100;
  var uSpacing = 10;
  var border = 20;
  var scalar = 100;
  var offset = (1 / (sales.length - 1)) * width;

  theContext.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height)

  theContext.beginPath();
  theContext.moveTo(0, sales[0]);
  for (var x = 1; x < sales.length; x++) {
    theContext.lineTo(x * offset, 100 - sales[x]);
  }
  theContext.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag
</canvas>
```

**EDIT**

Oops, forgot to invert Y-axis.

**Continual update**

Just for fun^^

```js
var sales = [52, 48, 74, 31, 47, 25, 67, 78, 45, 15, 85];

function graph() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var theContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var width = 300;
  var height = 100;
  var uSpacing = 10;
  var border = 20;
  var scalar = 100;
  var offset = (1 / (sales.length - 1)) * width;

  theContext.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
  theContext.strokeRect(0, 0, width, height)

  theContext.beginPath();
  theContext.moveTo(0, sales[0]);
  for (var x = 1; x < sales.length; x++) {
    theContext.lineTo(x * offset, 100 - sales[x]);
  }
  theContext.stroke();
}

setInterval(function() {
  sales.push(Math.random() * 100);
  if (sales.length > 100) {
    sales = sales.slice(sales.length - 100);
  }
  graph();
}, 1000/24)

graph();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border: 1px solid #ddd;">Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag
</canvas>
```